# How to correctly use Resque workers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-process, resque

I have the following tasks to do in a rails application:

- Download a video
- Trim the video with FFMPEG between a given duration (Eg.: 00:02 - 00:09)
- Convert the video to a given format
- Move the converted video to a folder

Since I wanted to make this happen in background jobs, I used 1 resque worker that processes a queue.

For the first job, I have created a queue like this
`@queue = :download_video` that does it's task, and at the end of the task I am going forward to the next task by calling `Resque.enqueue(ConvertVideo, name, itemId)`. In this way, I have created a chain of queues that are enqueued when one task is finished.

This is very wrong, since if the first job starts to enqueue the other jobs (one from another), then everything get's blocked with 1 worker until the first list of queued jobs is finished.

How should this be optimised? I tried adding more workers to this way of enqueueing jobs, but the results are wrong and unpredictable.

Another aspect is that each job is saving a status in the database and I need the jobs to be processed in the right order.

Should each worker do a single job from above and have at least 4 workers? If I double the amount to 8 workers, would it be an improvement?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) ?

As said in Sidekiq documentation :

> resque uses redis for storage and processes messages in a single-threaded process. The redis requirement makes it a little more difficult to set up, compared to delayed_job, but redis is far better as a queue than a SQL database. Being single-threaded means that processing 20 jobs in parallel requires 20 processes, which can take a lot of memory.
>
> sidekiq uses redis for storage and processes jobs in a multi-threaded process. It's just as easy to set up as resque but more efficient in terms of raw processing speed. Your worker code does need to be thread-safe.

So you should have two kind of jobs : download videos and convert videos and any download video job should be done in parallel (you can limit that if you want) and then each stored in one queue (the "in-between queue") before being converted by multiple convert jobs in parallel.

I hope that helps, this link explains quite well the best practices in Sidekiq : https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices

Answer (score 0):

As @Ghislaindj noted Sidekiq might be an alternative - largely because it offers plugins that control execution ordering.

See this list:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Related-Projects#execution-ordering

Nonetheless, yes, you should be using different queues and more workers which are specific to the queue. So you have a set of workers all working on the `:download_video` queue and then you other workers attached to the `:convert_video` queue, etc.

If you want to continue using Resque another approach would be to use delayed execution, so when you enqueue your subsequent jobs you specify a delay parameter.

`Resque.enqueue_in(10.seconds, ConvertVideo, name, itemId)`

The down-side to using delayed execution in Resque is that it requires the `resque-scheduler` package, so you're introducing a new dependency:

https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler

For comparison Sidekiq has delayed execution natively available.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered merging all four tasks into just one? In this case you can have any number of workers, one will do the job. It will work very predictable, you can even know how much time will take to finish the task. You also don't have problems when one of the subtasks takes longer than all others and it piles up in the queue.